# Some ns-3 building errors in cygwin windows7-64bit

Tags: cygwin, ns-3

Recently I need to do some network simulation in ns-3, but ns-3 is working on Linux. So I installed a cygwin on my Windows 7 and installed **'Base'**, **'Devel'** and **'Python'** module just like the tutorial showed.

the first problem is that when I built the ns-3 using command

```
./build.py
```

Then it showed something strange like

```
$ ./build.py
# Skip NetAnim (platform not supported)
# Build NS-3
Entering directory `./ns-3-dev'
Note: configuring ns-3 without pybindgen
 =>  /usr/bin/python waf configure
Setting top to                           : /home/Dell/workspace/ns-3-allinone/ns-3-dev
Setting out to                           : /home/Dell/workspace/ns-3-allinone/ns-3-dev/build
Checking for 'gcc' (C compiler)          : /usr/bin/gcc
Checking for cc version                  : 5.4.0
Checking for 'g++' (C++ compiler)        : /usr/bin/g++
Python is not supported in CygWin environment.  Try MingW instead.
```

the last line is strange because it skipped python check, but the line

```
'configure' finished successfully (45.850s)
```

still appeared. **So should I ignore it?**

And the second problem is when building went on, Something like

```
[ 966/1741] Compiling src/spectrum/model/aloha-noack-mac-header.cc
../src/wifi/model/dsss-error-rate-model.cc: In static function ‘static double ns3::DsssErrorRateModel::DqpskFunction(double)’:
../src/wifi/model/dsss-error-rate-model.cc:38:54: Error：‘M_PI’ is not declared in this scope.
   return ((std::sqrt (2.0) + 1.0) / std::sqrt (8.0 * M_PI * std::sqrt (2.0)))
                                                      ^

Waf: Leaving directory `/home/Dell/workspace/ns-3-allinone/ns-3-dev/build'
Build failed
```

Showed. So I googled this problem and find it may be caused by my c compiler. But no solution.

So what should I do? (Sorry 4 my poor English...)

Comment: check if CFLAGS or CXXFLAGS is including  any "-std=.." flag that restric the scope.

Comment: Could you describe it more specific. I never use cygwin or linux before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I must forgot some necessary plugins. If u have the same problem, just find a to-install list from internet and make sure using "sudo" command to install all the plugins like g++ and python.